# How to get config value in laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel

I want to get config value in my laravel app but when i use config to get config value it return the null value how can i resolve this issue. i google it several time but not found any proper solution so i put the question.thanks in advance.

this is my config/worldpay.php

```
<?php
return [
    'server' => "sandbox",
    'sandbox' => array(
        'service' => 'T_S_46a1ae07-fb66-4349-9f48-d10995936327',
        'client'  => 'T_C_b41133df-f03f-4f19-ad60-a8785fc19efe',
    ),

];
?>
```

this is my controller

```
public function worldpay(Request $request)
{
    $token    = $request->token;
    $total    = 50;
    $key      = config('worldpay.sandbox.client');
    dd($key);
}
```

when i `dd($key)` return null value.

Comment: Try config('worldpay.server')['sandbox']['client']

Comment: still return null value

Comment: Have you checked the spelling of the config file? it should be exactly worldpay.php but you've mentioned above worlpay.php

Comment: worldpay.php in my config file not worlpay

Comment: have you created this config file yourself? or it belongs to a package?

Comment: this file created my self not any package

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183406/discussion-between-shahid-hussain-and-tohid-dadashnezhad).

Comment: If your are in production server maybe your config is caching because you create yourself and maybe forget to clear cache.

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch value from your custom config file so...

```
$config = app('config')->get('worldpay');
$client = $config['sandbox']['client'];
```